# Captcha not visible on admin login form

Tags: captcha, magento1.9.3.1

I have enabled the admin **Captcha** feature for admin login and forget password form in admin area.

Captcha is visible in forget password, but not visible in admin login page.

I have cross check this in database also that Captcha is enabled for admin login page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the **js** bellow in your source code page, otherwise you add it in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('mage/captcha.js') ?>"></script>
```

Clear your Magento and browser cache.

Comment: this js is already include in login.phtml